# What is wrong with my code? For some reason, the last value in vetFinal seems to be memory junk

Tags: arrays, c

Make a program in C that, given two connections between the numbers containing the 8 and 9 values each respectively and obtained through the keyboard, provide the numbers that appear on the two lists. For example, if the connections are u =  {9, 32, 45, 21, 56, 67, 42, 55} and w = {24, 42, 32, 12, 45, 11, 67, 66, 78}, the function must provide the vector v =  {32, 45, 67, 42}.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n = 0;
    int u[8] = {};
    int w[9] = {};
    int v[n];

    //Inform values for the first vector
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      scanf("%i", &u[i]);
    }

    //Inform values for the second vector
    for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      scanf("%i", &w[i]);
    }

    //Check if there are overlapping values in both vectors and add them to the final vector.
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
      {
        if(u[i] == w[j])
        {
          n++;
          v[i] = u[i];
        }
      }
    }

    //Print the final vector
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("%i", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will be the result array if the first array contains for example values { 1, 1 } and the second array contains values { 1, 2, 2 }? will it be { 1 } or { 1, 1 }?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Is it? In that case it would be nicer to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      n++;
      v[i] = u[i];
```

Unfortunately the size of `v` is fixed at 0 above and won't be changed just because you changed `n`.

Normally we solve this with dynamic memory but you should be able to initalize v to have size 72 because you can't go around the inner loop more than 8*7 times..

```
    int v[72];
```